# Rotas no Angular 2+

Tags: angular, rotas

Minha aplicação começa no componente LoginComponente:

```
bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
```

No meu login routing module eu defini as seguintes rotas:

```
const loginRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dash', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'registrar', component: RegistrarComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(loginRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

A Dash deve ser acessada quando o usuário faz o login;

No meu login.component.html eu defini um ngIf que só vai aparecer a dash quando o usuário loga no sistema:

```
<div *ngIf="!usuarioautenticou" class="wrapper">
```

Neste template eu defini o router-outlet e botões para as chamadas das navegações:

```
<div>
     <button type="submit" routerLink="/dash" name="entrar" (click)="fazerLogin()" class="btn btn-success waves-effect" id="login-button">Entrar</button>
     <button type="button" routerLink="/registrar" class="btn btn-outline-success waves-effect">Registrar</button>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Tudo funciona perfeitamente por enquanto. Quando a aplicação está no localhost:4200 ela redireciona para a página de login. Quando clica em registrar ela altera para o componente de registro e quando clico em entrar ele me move para a tela de dash.

O problema é que a dash é um componente fixo que dentro dela vai ter outros componentes, então eu tentei colocar outro router-outlet dentro da dash:

```
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

dashboard.routing.module.ts:

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: BemvindoComponent },
];
```

Porém, o BemVindoComponent não aparece dentro da minha dash.
Ele já está como exports e é importado pelo meu módulo de rotas da dash.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem de colocar um nome ao segundo `router-outlet`

```
<router-outlet name="nomeASerDado"></router-outlet>
```

Ao definir nas rotas, especificar o outlet desejado

```
{path: 'caminho/a/ser/seguido', component: ComponenteQueSeraCarregado, outlet: 'nomeASerDado'}
```

E para fazer as alterações de rota, tem duas formas:

1. No HTML, através do routerLink

   ```
   <a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: ['caminho/da/view/primaria'], nomeASerDado: ['caminho/da/view/auxiliar']}}]"></a>
   ```
2. Através de um comando ao router

   ```
   router.navigate([{outlets: {primary: 'caminho/da/view/primaria', nomeASerDado: 'caminho/da/view/auxiliar'}}]);
   ```

Mas você só precisa usar essa forma de alteração de rota se precisar usar o outlet nomeado, caso contrário, pode usar assim:

```
routerLink="caminho/a/ser/seguido"
```

ou assim

```
router.navigate(['caminho/a/ser/seguido'])
```

Você pode tirar mais alguma ajuda [deste link.](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/)

Comment: Alterei para:   {path: 'dash', component: DashboardComponent, outlet:'primario'},
  {path: 'registrar', component: RegistrarComponent, outlet:'primario'} e
<button type="submit" routerLink="[{outlets: {primario: ['dash']" name="entrar" (click)="fazerLogin()" class="btn btn-success waves-effect" id="login-button">Entrar</button>
            <button type="button" routerLink="[{outlets: {primario: ['registrar']" class="btn btn-outline-success waves-effect">Registrar</button>
Ainda não deu certo

Comment: Você tem que colocar o atributo name no router-outlet e registrar a rota no módulo de roteamento

Comment: coloquei também...  <router-outlet name="primario"></router-outlet>

Comment: O routerLink no botão não está entre colchetes. Deveria ficar `[routerLink]=`

Comment: usando com colchetes a página nem carrega... e sem colchetes não funciona

Comment: Nos botões, o valor do atributo `routerLink` não está fechado corretamente. Você não fechou o `outlets` e nem o `[{`

Comment: Corrigi. agora a página carrega, mas o meu bemvindo component ainda não carrega dentro do segundo router-outlet. O primeiro eu defini como name "primario", o segundo deixei só router-outlet. Preciso nomear este também?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80348/discussion-between-mutlei-and-leticia).